# how to place the cursor to the place you last edited

Tags: vim

when I open a file using vim, I'd like vim put the cursor to the place where I last edited so that it can save me lot of searching time to go back to the last edited place in order to, might be, continue the unfinished edit work from that place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is mkview and loadview. See [:help :mkview](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mkview) :mkview outputs different information about your current window including:

- The scroll position and the cursor position in the file.

A common mapping for your .vimrc is:

```
au BufWinLeave *.py mkview
au BufWinEnter *.py silent loadview
```

to automatically run make and load views. Replace *.py accordingly.